# How to mount Windows Vista file share to remote headless Linux Centos 5.8 system?

Tags: network-share, centos5, windows-vista, putty, headless

I am trying to set up a network file share system such that a headless supercomputer running linux (CentOS 5.8) can access computer simulation files stored on a Windows Vista machine.

I have found guides for doing this on a home network, but the machine is across a college campus, and there is an additional hurdle that I am extremely new to linux.

I have set up access using PuTTY, but can only use this command line terminal from my vista machine.

Thus far I have set up file sharing for the directory I want to mount from vista. Looking at something like http://wiki.centos.org/TipsAndTricks/WindowsShares I have no idea how these computers communicate over my network, or what the distinction is between the machine name and share name. I can well enough type in commands and edit config files, if I only knew where to start and whether Vista needs a wizard's spell to play with Samba.

Any help offered to this noob would be greatly appreciated, as I am completely out of my depth on this task.

Answer (score 1):

You need to look into mount.cifs (http://linux.die.net/man/8/mount.cifs) which is a mechanism by which directories shared on a windows system can be mounted in Linux.  Also see http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-mount-cifs-windows-share/ - and, of course, Google.

Good luck.

Comment: Thanks so much. Is the domain something I set, or is it a name that my Vista machine has specifically? I used:

mount -t cifs -o username=win_username,password=win_password //my_ip_address/sharename /home/linux_username/sharename


So far I get "mount error 110: Connection timed out." I've googled and there seems to be myriad ways of getting this error. Any quick tips on troubleshooting?